# fgrep with string containing spaces inside ksh script

Tags: shell, grep, ksh

I am trying to write an `fgrep` statement removing records with a full record match from a file.  I can do this on the command line, but not inside a `ksh` script.  The code I am using boils down to these 4 lines of code:

```
   Header='abc def|ghi jkl' #I use the head command to populate this variable

   workfile=abc.txt

   command="fgrep -Fxv \'$Header\' $workfile" >$outfile

   $command
```

When I echo `$command` to STDIN the command is exactly what I would type on the command line (with the single quotes) and that works on the command line.  When I execute it within the `ksh` script (file) the single quotes seem not to be recognized because the errors show it is parsing on spaces.

I have tried back ticks, exec, eval, double quotes instead of single quotes, and not using the `$command` variable.  The problem remains.

Comment: when people try to build a variable `$cmd` and then "run it", is is usually because they're trying to do something that the shell can solve via a different path. Do you **really** need to run `$command`? I would refocus your effort on getting a normal shell script to work and then decide if you really need this extra level of indirection. And it's not clear about the `|` char in your `$header`. In a grep reg ex, that stands for `OR`; in the shell, of course, it is a `pipe`. So several issues here that are not clear. Update your Q (or change your tactics for this problem). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> I can do this on the command line, but not inside a ksh script

Here's a simple, portable, reliable solution using a ***heredoc***.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

workfile=abc.txt
outfile=out.txt  

IFS= read -r Header <<'EOF'
abc def|ghi jul
EOF

IFS= read -r command <<'EOF'
grep -Fxv "$Header" "$workfile" > "$outfile"
EOF

eval "$command"
```

**Explanation** :

(Comments can't be added to the script above because they would affect the lines in the **heredoc**)

```
IFS= read -r Header <<'EOF'                   # Line separated literal strings
abc def|ghi jul                               # Set into the $Header variable
EOF                                           # As if it were a text file

IFS= read -r command <<'EOF'                  # Command to execute
grep -Fxv "$Header" "$workfile" > "$outfile"  # As if it were typed into
EOF                                           # the shell command line

eval "$command"                               # Execute the command
```

The above example is the same as having a text file called **header.txt**, which contains the contents: `abc def|ghi jul` and typing the following command:

- ```
  grep -Fxvf header.txt abc.txt
  ```

The ***heredoc*** addresses the problem of the script operating differently than the command line ***as a result of*** quoting/expansions/escaping issues.

#### A Word of caution regarding `eval`:

The use of `eval` in this example is specific.  Please see [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for information on how `eval` can be misused and cause potentially very damaging results.

---

## **More Detail / Alternate Example:**

For the sake of completeness, clarity, and ability to apply this concept to other situations, some notes about the **heredoc** and an alternative demonstration:

This implementation of the ***heredoc*** *in this example* is specifically designed with the following criteria:

- **Literal** string assignment of contents, to the *variables* (using **'EOF'**)
- Use of the ***[eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)*** command to evaluate and execute the referenced variables within the heredoc itself.

---

## File or heredoc ?

One strength of using a **heredoc** combined with **grep -F** (`fgrep`), is the ability to treat a section of the script as if it were a file.

**Case for file:**

- You want to frequently paste "pattern" lines into the file, and remove them as necessary, **without** having to modify the script file.

**Case for heredoc:**

- You apply the script in an environment where specific files already exist, and you want to match specific exact literal patterns against it.

### Example:

- Scenario: I have 5 VPS Servers, and I want a script to produce a new `fstab` file but **to ensure it doesn't contain the exact line:**
- ```
  /dev/xvda1   /               ext3    errors=remount-ro,noatime,barrier=0 0       1
  ```

This scenario fits the type of situation addressed in this question.  I could use the boilerplate from the above code in this answer and modify it as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

workfile=/etc/fstab

IFS= read -r Header <<'EOF'
/dev/xvda1  /               ext3    errors=remount-ro,noatime,barrier=0 0       1
EOF

IFS= read -r command <<'EOF'
grep -Fxv "$Header" "$workfile"
EOF

eval "$command"
```

This would give me a new `fstab` file, without the line contained in the **heredoc**.

Comment: FYI - eval, exec these do not work.  I found the solution.  Call fgrep with the -f or --file option.  I can put the match string in the specified file.  That string can contain spaces, single quotes, double quotes, etc.

Comment: That's good, you need to be clear about what you're trying to achieve.  -  it wasn't clear whether you wanted to use a command variable specifically or if you just wanted the fgrep to work.

Comment: Your here-doc solution _is_ robust, but I still wouldn't promote it, because it's generally hard to understand the full implications of `eval`, and there are better non-`eval` solutions available. By contrast, your first solution is _not_ robust, and I encourage you to remove it (try with `Header="a'b"`, for instance).

Comment: `eval $command` is _not_ the same as `eval "$command"`, even though the difference will rarely surface: The former is passed as _multiple_ arguments that are fully shell-expanded _up front_, whereas
the latter is passed as a _single_ argument, that are _later_ (fully) shell-expanded by `eval`. Here's an example command where the difference surfaces: `command='cd / && echo *'`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.  That was a very incomplete statement of mine.  It seems that `eval $command` [respects/is subject to] the value of `$IFS`.  In the case where `IFS=` is added to the script before the `eval`, your example of `command='cd / && echo *'` (very interesting example by the way) is seen/processed exactly the same as if `"$command"` were quoted.   This is regardless of `set +f/-f`.

Comment: Have also deleted the first solution

Comment: @hmedia1: Thanks for updating; ++. Please also add `-r` to your read command so that `\ ` instances don't get "eaten" (try `read v <<<'a\b'; echo "$v"`). Also, I suggest adding a note that while `eval` is being used safely _in this case_, it is generally to be avoided. (P.S.: You must @-mention me for me to be notified of responses).

Comment: To make the `read` command _portable_, you can omit the `-d` option, which you don't need here, given that you're reading only a _single_ line. Also, there's no need for `IFS=$'\n'`, though for reading the header line, where you may want to preserve leading and trailing whitespace, use `IFS= read -r Header ...`, which will change `IFS` only _for that command_.

Comment: Re arguments passed to `eval`: Your `IFS= eval $command` is interesting too. The reason it comes out the same as `eval "$command"` in that case is that `cd /; echo *` is now seen as a _single_ word by the calling shell, and even though globbing is _attempted_, (unless `set -f` is in effect), it happens not to match anything, and the word is passed as-is.
In Bash, you can verify that globbing is still applied by setting `shopt -s failglob` before: `IFS= eval $command` will then _fail_, whereas `eval "$command"` won't. Generally, there's nothing special about how arguments are passed to `eval`.

Comment: @mklement0 ok ✓

Answer (score 1):

[Bash FAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) provides comprehensive guidance - while it is written for *Bash*, most of it applies to *Ksh* as well.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you want to stick with storing your command in a *variable* (defining a *function* is the better choice), use an *array*, which bypasses the quoting issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

Header='abc def|ghi jkl'

workfile=abc.txt

# Store command and arguments as elements of an array
command=( 'fgrep' '-Fxv' "$Header" "$workfile" ) 

# Invoke the array as a command.
"${command[@]}" > "$outfile"
```

Note: only a *simple* command can be stored in an array, and *redirections* can't be part of it.

---

<sup>[1] The function examples use `local` to create local variables, which `ksh` doesn't support. Omit `local` to make do with shell-global variables instead, or use `function <name> {...}` syntax with `typeset` instead of `local` to declare local variables in `ksh`.</sup>